# javascript append from foreach loop not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing simple changelog for my website that uses github api and appends tag  but it doesnt work.

this is my code:

```
<p id="testing"></p>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("testing");
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/test234/test/releases").done(function (json) {
for each (release in json) {
c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(release.tag_name));
}
});
</script>
```

I think something is wrong with my foreach loop.

Any help is welcome I am stuck here for a long time

Comment: `for each` looks like a syntax error.  Perhaps this is just a typo?  Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer but my problem is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way to use `forEach`:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("testing");
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/4u7157/DOWNLOADS/releases").done(function (json) {
     json.forEach((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.tag_name));
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="testing"></p>
```

You can also use `JQuery` as follows:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("testing");
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/4u7157/DOWNLOADS/releases").done(function (json) {
     $.each(json, function( index, e ){
          console.log(e);
          c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.tag_name));
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="testing"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the reason is that your syntax is appropriate for arrays but here json is object so this syntax will not work unless you use Object.Entries

```
const entries = Object.entries(json)
  for(const [index,obj] of entries){
    c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.tag_name))
  }
```

or you can use for each method provided for objects like this :

```
json.forEach(function(value,key,obj){
    c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value.tag_name))
});
```

Rest is all good , you just need to look for these changes.